# R Fuzzy String Matching: Matching a a text fragment to the original text

Tags: r, text-mining, string-matching

I have been given the task to match a text fragment (a few sentences) to the whole text from which it originated. The problem is that the texts have been altered slightly through several worksteps so they do not exactly match anymore.

Why? Well, the text fragments have been coded (> 100 h of work) but the date of the texts publication (essential) has not been extracted and no id has been used to link fragments and orignal (It wasn't me). To reconnect this information i want to match these texts.

What i have tried so far:

- Normal matching (grep) of fragment and whole text. --> Does not work, the texts are to dissimilar OR my loop is just broken (see loop example below)

  `for (i in 1:length(diss_cut$Seq)) {
  x <- list()
  x[i] <- grep(diss_cut[i,10],x = extract$Seq, fixed = TRUE )
  }`

Where `diss_cut[i,10]` is the column with the short sequence patterns

- Fuzzy string matching using the stringdist's amatch algorithm.

First on the raw data, then on a sequence made out of the first letter of each word. The sequences have been cleaned of special characters, spaces, punctuation and converted to lower case.

An example for such a sequence is :*aafdalgedsapupfdedmuefvmbznz*

To account for the different string lengths i adjusted the amatch algorithm's (lv and osm) 
penalty for deletions to 0.000001 in the hope that the excess text would be deleted and good matches emerge.

```
amatch(diss_cut$Segment,extract$edata,maxDist = 20,
                     method = c("lv"), weight = c(d = 0.000001, i = 1, s = 1, t = 1))
```

Sadly this has not worked and I'm running out of ideas.

Anybody having an idea how to approach the *text fragment to whole text matching* issue? It would make a PhD student extremely happy (again not me).

Comment: Could you give a single small example, perhaps?

Comment: The sequence to be matched are like this (converted to lowercase)

dibfagvhzmidjvhabnsdtbtudvaadaasb 

and they should be matched to the corresponding original, longer string.

Comment: By the way: The way i constructed the loop the search for exact matches looks like this:

`for (i in 1:length(diss_cut$Seq)) {
  x <- list()
  x[i] <- grep(diss_cut[i,10],x = extract$Seq, fixed = TRUE )
}`

Comment: Have a look at the protein alignment methods, e.g. here: http://a-little-book-of-r-for-bioinformatics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/chapter4.html , you could assume you have a longer protein sequence = your original text, and the shorter one = your text to find. Just an idea.